# How to re-render a lightning component when some attribute value is changed?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, javascript-controller

I need to rerender a component when an attribute value is changed. I tried to put the init handler code into a helper function and called it in valueChange event handler but it did not work. Please give me some suggestions.

```
<!--Handler-->
<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.dfButtonId}" action="{!c.dfButtonIdChange}"/>

<!--js controller-->
doInit: function(component, event, helper){
    //This code is working correctly
},
dfButtonIdChange:function(component, event, helper){
   //I need to rerender the component here
}
```

Comment: Similar question http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/122297/refreshing-lightning-component-based-on-field-change

Comment: Did you get an error? Would you be willing to share some code that demonstrates it not working?

Comment: @sfdcfox the code is working correctly but I am not able to rerender the component when the value is changed. I tried refreshView but it refreshes everything which is currently in the view.

Comment: What is dfButtonId?

Comment: What are you trying to rerender? Some more information about what happens in the dfButtonIdChange function would be helpful.

Comment: Why do you need to manually rerender your component? The framework will detect any attribute changes automatically and rerender dirty values.

Comment: @TrevorBliss thanks.That answered my question. I apologize for the wrong question. I am still having hard  time migrating from VF to Lightning.

Comment: No worries, the community here is pretty helpful so keep the questions coming. I'll move my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 3):

The framework will detect any attribute changes automatically and rerender dirty values so you shouldn't need to manually track and rerender.

Comment: This was true for me up until now. I am changing attributes present directly in markup  in <aura:if > but nothing is rerendering. I don't know why. Any idea?

Comment: Do you have a more complete example?

Comment: We have a case where this is happening. We are creating two arrays with references of objects. We are then dynamically creating components to display each item in those arrays. If we update a value in the original object and print out the value from `component.get('v.myarray')`, the value is updated in the array. However, the DOM doesn't get updated with the new value. Because of this we are trying to figure out a way to force a refresh.

Comment: @dsharrison I have the same issue - did you ever find out a solution?

Comment: @dharrison - i've got the same issue as well my components are next in 2 aura if's dont know if that has something to do with it